# R and database Roracle

Tags: database, r, oracle, rstudio

I am using **Rstudio** (or R) with the package ROracle to connect to db. However I have the following error message

```
Error in .oci.Connect(.oci.drv(), username = username, password = password,  : 
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

One possible solution is to add the following line to the `.Renviron` file. But I guess my R does not read this file. How can I be sure, or force R to read `.Renviron`? (I am using Windows.)

Some other suggestion from Oracle are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/net12150.htm).

I am so grateful for every hint.

Comment: Is this still an active question for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the `.Renviron` file with the `readRenviron` function. Just make sure you enter the correct file path.

```
readRenviron(".Renviron")
```

Comment: That is true, thanks a lot. However the problem is still there.